# Nativescript Listview not scrollable

Tags: android, listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing an app using Nativescript Vue. I have an WrapLayout and inside it I have ListView (and other components too).

```
     <ListView for="event in selectedDayNotes" class="home__notes-list">
        <v-template>
          <WrapLayout class="home__notes-list-item">
            <Label class="home__notes-list-item-note" :text="event.title" />
            <Label class="home__notes-list-item-time" :text="event.startDate.getHours() + ':' + event.startDate.getMinutes() + ' - '" />
            <Label class="home__notes-list-item-time" :text="event.endDate.getHours() + ':' + event.endDate.getMinutes()" />
          </WrapLayout>
        </v-template>
      </ListView>
```

selectedDayNotes is a computed property returning an array.

SCSS:

```
  &__notes-list-item {
    background: white;
  }

  &__notes-list-item-note {
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__notes-list-item-time {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
```

So then I add items to the ListView in the app (selectedDayNotes updates and the ListView shows new elements), but ListView is not scrollable. What should I do to make it scroll?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I managed to get this working wrapping ListView into ScrollView. Kinda strange - the docs say nothing about it.

Here is the code:

```
      <ScrollView class="home__notes-list-wrapper">
        <ListView for="event in selectedDayNotes" class="home__notes-list">
          <v-template>
          //whatever you want inside some sort of layout
            <WrapLayout class="home__notes-list-item">
              <Label class="home__notes-list-item-note" :text="event.title" />
              <Label class="home__notes-list-item-time" :text="event.startDate.getHours() + ':' + event.startDate.getMinutes() + ' - '" />
              <Label class="home__notes-list-item-time" :text="event.endDate.getHours() + ':' + event.endDate.getMinutes()" />
            </WrapLayout>
          </v-template>
        </ListView> 
      </ScrollView>
```

Also I set desired ScrollView height in CSS.

Comment: It's not recommended to use ListView within ScrollView. Because ListView itself is an extended version of ScrollView, hence ListView should be scrollable itself. If you still have issues with scrolling, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.